# XSLT trnasformation of huge number of xml file (>1000) it crashes

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-1.0

I want **to transform the results from more than 1000 xml files to a html** presentation in a browser.

First, I have created a xml file, that contains the list all 1000 xml files.

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>  
<ResultFiles> 
<FailureMemoryDescription> 
D:\TMACS_DATA\Projects\VW\EV5012_04\Diagnosis\TKWINX_FAILUREMEMORYDESCRIPTION_BB93284.XML 
</FailureMemoryDescription> 
<ResultFile>file1.xml</ResultFile>
<ResultFile>file2.xml</ResultFile>
<ResultFile>file3.xml</ResultFile>
.....
<ResultFile>file1000.xml</ResultFile>
</ResultFiles>
```

Now, I have `test.xsl` where I have written code to display the result from all above 1000 files in a browser. But, unfortunately **it crashes**. If I am considering the list upto 50 number of xml file, then it works fine. But with a huge number of file (>1000), it crashes.

Could anybody help me in this regard ?

Thank You

Comment: Well which XSLT processor do you use, how exactly does your XSLT code look like? And which error message do you get on that "crash"? Does the XSLT processor simply run out of memory? Some XSLT processors have extension functions to discard a process from memory once processed, see http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!functions/saxon/discard-document.

Comment: also, if you reply to the request for more information, please edit your question, using the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box for code and data. That is to say, don't reply with code and data in comments ;-) Then add a comment that you have updated your question. Good luckl

Comment: Hi, Please find the details here.                                                               <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:date="http://www.exslt.org/functions"
                xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">                      Regarding the crash, i mean to tell when i just click the xml file, it just display xml raw data. it does not follow xslt.